# Lost WebSocket connection with Safari while running a Bokeh server

Tags: nginx, websocket, safari, bokeh

I'm setting up a Bokeh plot on a remote server and I'm having this problem with Safari. When I connect to the website, the plot shows up, but instantly, the WebSocket connection closes itself, as if the browser was closed.

When I try with Chrome, everything is fine.

Here is my reverse proxy config (nginx):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name bokeh_host;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.nginx-debian.html;

    access_log  /srv/log/bokeh.access.log;
    error_log   /srv/log/bokeh.error.log;

    location / {

    }

    location /bokeh_plot {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/static;
    }

}
```

Here is my bokeh command:

```
bokeh serve bokeh_plot.py --port 5000 --host *.domain.com
```

Here is what I see in the Terminal:

[image]

As you can see, the WebSocket connection closes itself right after being created. In the end, I can see the plot, but it's not interactive anymore since the WS connection is lost.

Is this something with Safari? Does someone have seen this bug too? Or maybe it is because of my config?

Comment: We've noticed issues with websockets in the current Safari release: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6196. The current thinking is that it's a Safari issue.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is a (quite recent) Safari problem. It seems to happen only when plots are too big.

Anyway, I tried it with [Safari Technology Preview R28](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/), as suggested on GitHub, and it works well. I guess we'll have to wait for the next Safari update.